# How to avoid vim inside vim for git/mercurial merge?

Tags: bash, git, vim, neovim

I use a terminal inside vim to run my commands.
I have set vim as my merge tool (in git and mercurial).

During rebase, when there's a conflict that needs manual merging, the terminal opens a vim instance inside it for merging.
With this, I have vim running inside vim. That often creates key binding conflicts between the host vim and the vim inside it.

**Is there a way I can make the terminal use its host vim for conflict resolution (by opening a new tab or something) instead of creating a new vim instance inside itself ?**

Comment: Maybe create a custom mergetool script that starts vim only if you are not inside vim.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, any idea how I can communicate with the host vim from the terminal ? (as the script I would create would run inside the terminal)

I actually have asked about that in a separate question:  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057107/vim-neovim-callback-on-terminal-command-completion

Comment: You may be able to set an environment variable in the `vimrc` and test for it in the custom start script

Comment: you can check if the terminal is run inside vim like that: `env | grep VIMRUNTIME` may help you

Comment: Is this a graphical Vim that you're using (as the outer Vim) or one inside a terminal of its own?

Comment: Terminal all the way (I do everything over ssh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Neovim there is a plugin [neovim-remote](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote).

For vim compiled with `+clientserver`, you can start vim as a server and connect to it with `--servername` and `--remote`. Check this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/9790dv/avoiding_nested_vim_in_terminal_buffers/).